# Selenium not finding input box

Tags: python, selenium

I am getting the following error while trying to find an input box using both xpath and id.

```
NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"[id="sys_display.incident.caller_id"]"}
```

The piece of HTML code is as follows:

```
<input id="sys_display.incident.caller_id" name="sys_display.incident.caller_id" aria-labelledby="label.incident.caller_id" type="search" autocomplete="off" autocorrect="off" value="" ac_columns="user_name;first_name;last_name" ac_order_by="name" data-type="ac_reference_input" data-completer="AJAXTableCompleter" data-dependent="company" data-dependent-value="" data-ref-qual="" data-ref="incident.caller_id" data-ref-key="null" data-ref-dynamic="false" data-name="caller_id" data-table="sys_user" class="form-control element_reference_input" style="; " spellcheck="false" onfocus="if (!this.ac) addLoadEvent(function() {var e = gel('sys_display.incident.caller_id'); if (!e.ac) new AJAXTableCompleter(gel('sys_display.incident.caller_id'), 'incident.caller_id', 'company', ''); e.ac.onFocus();})" aria-required="true" role="combobox" aria-autocomplete="list" aria-owns="AC.incident.caller_id" aria-expanded="false" title="" aria-invalid="false">
```

---

I tried the following code snippets to find the input box.

- Using xpath:

  ```
  name_input_button=driver.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="sys_display.incident.caller_id"]')
  driver.implicitly_wait(20)
  name_input_button.send_keys('some name')
  ```
- Using id:

  ```
  input_elmnt = WebDriverWait(driver, 100).until(EC.element_located_to_be_selected((By.ID, 'sys_display.incident.caller_id')))
  action = ActionChains(driver)
  action.move_to_element(input_elmnt).send_keys('some name').send_keys(Keys.ENTER).perform()
  ```
- Using CSS selector is also not working:

  ```
  # name_input_button=driver.find_element_by_css_selector('*[aria-labelledby="label.incident.caller_id"]')
  # driver.implicitly_wait(20)
  # name_input_button.send_keys('some name')
  ```

---

Can anyone let me know where I am going wrong?

Comment: Can you share the URL. If not, post HTML code in the question.

Comment: Does the xpath `//*[@id="sys_display.incident.caller_id"]` locate an element in the DOM. Check if the element is in an `iframe` or `shadow root` .

Comment: Can you share the page URL ?